# how to read contacts when app is terminated in android 13?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm developing an Android application and I need to read contacts from the user's device. In previous versions of Android, I was able to achieve this functionality while the app was running or in the background. However, with the release of Android 13, I'm uncertain whether it's still possible to read contacts when the app is completely killed or not running.

Specifically, I would like to know if Android 13 allows an application to access the device's contacts even when it's not actively running in the foreground or background. My goal is to retrieve contact information such as names, phone numbers, and email addresses for various purposes within my application.

I have researched extensively, but I couldn't find any concrete information regarding this particular scenario in Android 13. Therefore, I would appreciate any insights, guidance, or references to relevant documentation or official announcements from Google regarding this matter.

To summarize, my question is:

```
In Android 13, is it still possible for an application to read contacts even when the app is killed or not running? If so, what are the necessary steps or requirements to achieve this functionality?
```

Please note that I'm specifically asking about Android 13, as the behavior and capabilities of previous Android versions might differ from the latest release. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: An app that's not running can, by definition, not read contacts.

Comment: If your app isn't running, it can't do anything.  So what you were describing was never happening.  It may not have been running an Activity, but some part of your app was running.

Answer (score 0):

Not just contact read permission you need to add query intent in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    <!-- For overall Android support -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application>
        ...
    </application>
    <!-- For Android 13+ support -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```